# Finding the expectation of a random variable ($E[\min(X,a)]$)

Tags: probability

I will give some context first, then i'll ask the question.

Suppose you have a random variable $Y = h(X)$, such that

$ h(x) = \begin{cases} 0 & x < a  \\ 
x-a & a \leq x < b\\
b-a  & x \geq b \end{cases} $

$a < b$,and   $a,b \in \mathbb{R}$

Now,let $g(x)$ be the density of $X$. The expectation och $Y$ is then:

$E[Y]= E[h(X)] = \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}h(x)g(x)dx = \int_{-\infty}^{a}h(x)g(x)dx  + \int_{a}^{b}h(x)g(x)dx +\int_{b}^{+\infty}h(x)g(x)dx = 0 + \int_{a}^{b}(x-a)g(x)dx + \int_{b}^{+\infty}(b-a)g(x)dx = \int_{0}^{b-a}xg(x+a)dx + (b-a)(1- G(b)) $

Lets define a function: $L(a) = E[\min(X,a)]$ for some random variable $X$, where :

$ \min(x,a) = \begin{cases} x & x \leq a  \\ 
a & x > a \\
\end{cases} $

The expectation of Y togheter with this newly defined function can be written as: $E[ Y]  = E[h(X)] = L(b) - L(a)$

Could someone help me to show how $E[Y]$ can be written as $L(b) - L(a)$.

Surely it must boil down to finding $E[\min(Y,a)], E[\min(Y,b)]$ but i don't know how to do it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $a\leq b$ then:$$h\left(x\right)=\min\left(x,b\right)-\min\left(x,a\right)$$ so that:$$\mathbb{E}Y=\mathbb{E}h\left(X\right)=\mathbb{E}\left[\min\left(X,b\right)-\min\left(X,a\right)\right]=\mathbb{E}\min\left(X,b\right)-\mathbb{E}\min\left(X,a\right)=L\left(b\right)-L\left(a\right)$$

Comment: this question: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2538880/expected-value-integral-with-min is similar, but less complicated than the one the OP posted here. Still, though, I am having trouble applying what you and he did here to what I need to find there. Could you please help me with that one? Essentially, I need to figure out $\mathbb{E}[\min(X,l)]$ where $l$ is the maximum allowable value of $x$. Thank you.